# YouTube JavaScript API - play not fired when player hidden

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm controlling the YouTube iFrame player via the YT API. It works fine on normal cases, but in my process, there is a state when the player must be display:none; After I show the player again with display:block; it works fine except it doesn't fire the usual events.

http://jsfiddle.net/wDDuW/

Test case:

1. Start the video with the normal play button on the player - the play
   start event will be fired
2. Stop the video the the button below, it
   will make a .stopVideo(); and hide the parent element of the YouTube
   iframe.
3. Click on the show button, which will set it to
       display:block; again
4. Start the video again with the play control, there won't be any event from the YouTube player anymore.

Do you know any way to solve this problem? (Do not hide the video's parent element is not an option :( )

```
<div>
    <div id="test" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
</div>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<br />
<textarea id="console" style="height: 500px;"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var vars = {
    enablejsapi: 1,
    origin: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host,
    autoplay: 0,
    theme: 'dark',
    modestbranding: 1,
    wmode: "opaque",
    rel: 0,
    vq: 'default'
};
var c = $('#console');
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    var player = $("#test"),
        playercontainer = player.parent();
    playerobj = new YT.Player(player.attr("id"), {
        videoId: '0_aFSNB8E5Y',
        wmode: 'opaque',
        playerVars: vars,
        events: {
            onStateChange: function (state) {
                switch (state.data) {
                    case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
                        c.val("play started\n" + c.val());
                        break;
                        //case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
                    case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
                        c.val("play ended\n" + c.val());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $('#stop').click(function () {
        playerobj.stopVideo();
        playercontainer.css('display', 'none');
    });
    $('#show').click(function () {
        playercontainer.css('display', 'block');
        playerobj.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'test');
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems like it is a known issue for the Flash based YouTube API. You should use visibility:hidden instead of display:none.